# Gnome-Terminal : Hide tab bar in fullscreen mode

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

How to hide tab bar only in full screen mode for gnome-terminal? (when I press F11)

Comment: Which tab are you referring to I'm using the F-11 in Gnome and it only shows the full screen and no tabs are showing

Comment: I hope you are using gnome-terminal and not *gnome* as mentioned in your post. press shift+ctrl+t you will get another tab in gnome-terminal.

Comment: `gnome-terminal` does not have such an option.

Comment: The `Menubar`? Right mouse click and unselect `Show Menubar`

Comment: Yes, there are tabs in the gnome-terminal. Yes, you can open a tab by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+T. All these comments are misleading. And i'd like an answer as well.

Comment: I guess there is still no option?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there is a toggle in options but someone has commented out the option to have tabs "never" show.

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/mainline/src/org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml#L46

If this option was uncommented you could edit the options with dconf-editor.

I *think* this option would hide the tabs.

So first you need to find out how to get this change pushed through the gnome-terminal change process.

And there is this thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1725620